# Stack not empty but Empty Stack Exception thrown

Tags: java, exception, stack, is-empty, peek

This is a helper method in my Swing class. I am writing a program that calculates the possible pairs of tree that monkeys can swing between, given the number of trees and their height.

```
public class Swing {

 private long processSwing(int N, Scanner sc){
  int i=0;
  long count=0;
  Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<>();
  while(i<N){//scanning loop
   int currTree=sc.nextInt();
   if(s1.isEmpty()){//if s1 is empty(only will happen at the first tree, because consequently s1 will always be filled)
    s1.push(currTree);//push in first tree
   }
   else{
    while(currTree>s1.peek()){//this loop removes all the previous trees which are smaller height, and adds them into pair counts
     s1.pop();
     count++;
    }
    if(!s1.isEmpty()){//if the stack isnt empty after that, that means there is one tree at the start which is same height or bigger. add one pair.
     count++;
    }
    if(currTree==s1.peek()){
     s1.pop();
    }
    s1.push(currTree);// all trees will always be pushed once. This is to ensure that the stack will never be empty.
   }//and the tree at the lowest stack at the end of every iteration will be the tallest one
   i++;
  }
  return count;
 }
}
```

This portion ensures that if the stack s1 is empty, it will push in the very first integer i have scanned into the stack.

```
if(s1.isEmpty()){
     s1.push(currTree);//push in first tree
}
```

Subsequently, the else condition runs:

```
 else{
    while(currTree>s1.peek()){
     s1.pop();
     count++;
    }
    if(!s1.isEmpty()){
     count++;
    }
    if(currTree==s1.peek()){
     s1.pop();
    }
    s1.push(currTree);
    }
```

After the code successfully pushes in the first integer, it will throw an EmptyStackException, for s1.peek() method at the line

```
 while(currTree>s1.peek())
```

Why is this so? I mean i've checked and s1 isn't empty when the 2nd iteration runs.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop may remove all the elements of the `Stack`, at which point the `Stack` will become empty and `s1.peek()` will throw an exception.

In order to prevent that from happening, add a condition to your loop :

```
while(!s1.isEmpty() && currTree>s1.peek()) {
  s1.pop();
  count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You remove the object in `s1.pop();`, so in the last iteration `s1` is empty. You need to check that `s1` isn't empty before the `peek()`. Change to

```
while(!s1.isEmpty() && currTree > s1.peek()) {
    s1.pop();
    count++;
}
```